# Run a method only for 10 seconds asynchronously android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, future, threadpoolexecutor

I have a set of actions or a functions which needs to be executed only for a specific amount of time say X seconds. How can I achieve this task and display success or failure if I could completely execute function in specified time.

I don't want to block the Android UI while performing activation. Tried using do while using getCurrentTime() but this blocks UI.

Comment: post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

In activity class file:

```
private boolean status = false; //set a initial flag   
private Handler customHandler;
customHandler = new Handler();
Runnable currentThreadTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      status = customfunction();
    //call your function,suppose the function executed successfully,'status' changed to ture.   
    }
};
customHandler.post(currentThreadTask);

public boolean customfunction(){
 //Time consuming operations
 return true;
}
```

And create a countDownTimer, like this:

```
     new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

         }

         public void onFinish() {//5 seconds passed
             //Check 'status' value
             //If status is still equal false,then customfunction executed failed in 5 seconds
             //otherwise it successed.
         }
      }.start();
```